# Create n Combinations Using While Loop in R

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, combinations

Starting with a data frame of City, Condition and Order Number, I'm trying to create *n* possible combinations of Order Numbers by City & Condition ([1], [2], [3], [1]&[2], [1]&[3], [2]&[3], [1]&[2]&[3]).

```
library(gtools)
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(City = c(rep("St. Louis", 3), rep("Chicago", 2)), 
              Condition = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 2)),
              Order.No = round(runif(5,10,100),0))
```

Splitting by City & Condition:

```
dat_groups <- lapply(split(dat, list(dat$City, dat$Condition)), function(x) {
    x$Order.No
})

> dat_groups
$Chicago.A
numeric(0)

$`St. Louis.A`
[1] 36 81 47

$Chicago.B
[1] 89 95

$`St. Louis.B`
numeric(0)
```

I'm able to use a while() loop with "combn" as my container for *n* to get close to a combination solution, however I am unable to save the output to a list object in an acceptable format.

```
combn <- 4
counter <- 0
while (counter <= combn) {
    counter <- counter + 1
    temp <- lapply(dat_groups, function(x) {
        n_obs <- length(x)
        if(n_obs == 0) {
            NA
        }
            if(n_obs > 0 & n_obs >= counter) {
                combinations(n_obs, counter, x)       
            } else {
                NA
            }
        })
print(temp)
}

$Chicago.A
[1] NA

$`St. Louis.A`
     [,1]
[1,]   36
[2,]   47
[3,]   81

$Chicago.B
     [,1]
[1,]   89
[2,]   95

$`St. Louis.B`
[1] NA

$Chicago.A
[1] NA

$`St. Louis.A`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   36   47
[2,]   36   81
[3,]   47   81

$Chicago.B
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   89   95

$`St. Louis.B`
[1] NA

$Chicago.A
[1] NA

$`St. Louis.A`
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   36   47   81
...............
truncated
```

The code above gets close by listing all of the single combinations, then the doubles followed by the triples for each City & Condition, but I can not figure out how to remove the NAs, close the holes and then save to a list object like below.

The desired final solution should look like the following:

```
[[1]]
[1] "36"

[[2]]
[1] "81"

[[3]]
[1] "47"

[[4]]
[1] "36" "81"

[[5]]
[1] "36" "47"

[[6]]
[1] "81" "47"

[[7]]
[1] "36" "81" "47"

[[8]]
[1] "89"

[[9]]
[1] "95"

[[10]]
[1] "89" "95"
```

Thank you for taking a look and any help you can offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` to get a data.frame of lists:

```
library(dplyr)
newdat <- dat %>% group_by(City, Condition) %>%
                  summarise(lists = list(lapply(1:n(), 
                            function(z){combinations(v=Order.No, r=z, n=n())}))) 
newdat
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
Groups: City [?]

       City Condition     lists
     (fctr)    (fctr)     (chr)
1   Chicago         B <list[2]>
2 St. Louis         A <list[3]>
```

The `newdat$lists` column now has all your subsamples of each level of City:Condition in a list.

To get it in the same format as your desired output, we need to do a little list wrangling:

```
unlist(lapply(unlist(newdat$lists, recursive = FALSE), 
               function(x){as.list(data.frame(t(x)))}), recursive = FALSE)
$X1
[1] 89

$X2
[1] 95

$t.x.
[1] 89 95

$X1
[1] 36

$X2
[1] 47

$X3
[1] 81

$X1
[1] 36 47

$X2
[1] 36 81

$X3
[1] 47 81

$t.x.
[1] 36 47 81
```

EDIT: As a function:

```
lister <- function(data, numgroups){
    data %>% group_by(City, Condition) %>%
        summarise(lists = list(lapply(1:min(numgroups, n()), 
                                      function(z){combinations(v=Order.No, r=z, n=n())}))) 
}
```

eg:

```
lister(dat, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @jeremycg.  Won't using n() always lead to using all of the Order Numbers for each City/Condition group?  This is the heart of my problem.  I need the ability to set a variable n and apply that to each group regardless of how many Order Numbers each group has.  i.e. Group One has 15 Order Numbers and n=2, so I only want to see all 1:2 combinations, not 1:15 combinations.

Comment: sure, in that case, change `n()` to your desired number, or wrap the whole thing in a function, using `function(numberofrepeats) ....` and replace the two `n()`s with your variable

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with goup_by so I'm struggling with how I could wrap your code in another function.  I'm pretty sure it'll have to be in a function() though with some kind of if() else conditional because it will bomb if the number of Orders for a given group is less than _n_.

Comment: no problem: see the edit - I've used min, so it takes whichever is lower, groups asked for, or n().

Comment: Very clever solution and does exactly what I needed!  Works great.  Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I just realized your code is not quite sufficient.  The "lapply(1:min(numgroups, n())" part keeps the code from cycling through the entire length of the group.  Using the code with "lister(dat, 2)" will omit the 2nd element for St. Louis.  It needs to be something like "lapply(1:n()", but for some reason that keeps giving me an error too.  "  r > n and repeats.allowed=FALSE"

Comment: I think the fix is to change `n=min(numgroups, n())` to `n=n()`? I'll edit the answer

Comment: Appears to be rock solid now.  Thanks so much for the edit!  Much appreciated.